# vertical smooth scroll up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> Note: may be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279409/is-there-any-plugin-like-smooth-div-scroll-that-scrolls-content-vertically-up?rq=1)

I want a vertical slider but, for a group of boxs instead of image. 
I tried to use:

- `window.location.href = "#feed_box";`
- `scrollTo`
- `scrollTop`

All of them where working fine except `scrollTop` but, the problem with `window.location.href`  was all the boxes have same id 'cause they all are echoed (php) from a `while` loop .So, it takes to the same box insted of the next.

jQuery:

```
var x= $(window).scrollTop();
$("#feed_up").click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: x - 960 }, 550);
});
$("#feed_down").click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: x + 960 }, 550);
});`
```

The problem in this script is it skips one or two box(post).

Briefly, i want this code to not skip a box or `window.location.href` to not to get the same box `id`.

Comment: _“the problem with window.location.href was all the boxes have same id 'cause they all are echoed (php) from a while loop”_ – that is an error in your HTML generation then, that you need to fix – ids must be _unique_ within a document.

Comment: Could you tell me how can i do that with a while loop. (post that in answer)

Answer (score 0):

> the problem with window.location.href was all the boxes have same id 'cause they all are echoed (php) from a while loop”

– that is an error in your HTML generation then, that you need to fix – ids must be unique within a document.

by using this echo `<div id="' . $row["id"] 'align="center"></div>` this would give the box id to div